# Group matrix data by row and display result as matrix with dimnames

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following code:

```
mat = matrix(c(1, 3, 4, 11, 13, 13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
mat_grouped = apply(mat, 1, function(row) tapply(row, as.factor(row), length))
```

The output is the following list:

```
[[1]]
1 3 4 
1 1 1 

[[2]]
11 13 
 1  2
```

However I would like the output to be displayed as the matrix with the column names given by all the values in the matrix and grouped by row:

```
     1 3 4 11 13
[1,] 1 1 1  0  0
[2,] 0 0 0  1  2
```

Is it possible to get my data in this form?

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
table(row(mat), mat)

   mat
    1 3 4 11 13
  1 1 1 1  0  0
  2 0 0 0  1  2
```

To explain:

`table()` creates contingency tables by (cross) tabulating values.  In this case there is the original matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    4
[2,]   11   13   13
```

And a second matrix of row indices the same shape as the matrix generated by `row(mat)`:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
```

The `table()` function returns counts of the co-occurrence of these two sets of values.

Comment: thank you, I am having difficulty understanding the arguments to the table function and how the table is generated, do you have a reference for that? RDocumentation isn't helpful

Comment: @NeileshVinjamuri - see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tabulate` instead, with `nbins=max(mat)`.

```
> t(apply(mat, 1, tabulate, nbins=max(mat)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     0     2
```

To get the desired output format , do

```
> t(apply(mat, 1, tabulate, nbins=max(mat))) |> `colnames<-`(seq_len(max(mat))) |>
+   {\(.) .[, colSums(.) > 0]}()
     1 3 4 11 13
[1,] 1 1 1  0  0
[2,] 0 0 0  1  2
```